# appendTo a form on another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, appendto

I was able to use JSfiddle to create a appendTo event. By clicking on the image, I am able to get the caption for those images printed in a list in another div. But what if i wanted it to be appended to another page into a form?

Also, how do i remove an item after its been added? The code that i currently have allows me to appendTo, but I have no idea how to undo this event... any suggestions?

Here is JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jhyqt5/cBsqN/20/

and the Code:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="caption">Blueberry</div>
    <img src="https://scontent-a-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/1394351_529524313783586_609777864_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="caption">Walnuts</div>
    <img src="https://scontent-b-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/1377244_529524413783576_249384396_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="caption">Craisins</div>
    <img src="https://scontent-b-pao.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/1378714_529524353783582_129148654_n.jpg" class="img-circle">
</div>
   <br>
       <br>
<div class="foodlist">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .7;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
}
.wrapper:hover .caption {
    display: block;
}
.wrapper.active .caption {
    display: block;
    opacity: .8;
    background: #38ACD5;
}
```

JS

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var caption = $(this).find(".caption").text();
    $("<li>" + caption + "</li>").appendTo("div.foodlist");
});
```

Bottomline:

1) appendTo and Undo function
2) appendTo a form on a another page

Thanks :)

Comment: You could use an array as an intermediate step. Add/remove items to the array and write the entire array using `.html`. For #2, you can pass data between pages - depends on your language: php, asp?

Comment: When you say "appended to another page into a form", what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean a different browser page?  If so, is that browser page loaded in another window?  Or it will be loaded some time in the future?

Comment: you can use $.('#id').slideUp(0); to instantly hide a div, but the space will "open" up too. I do not know what you mean append to "another page" -- if you mean an entirely separate tab, without POSTing to the new page itself... idk if that's possible.

Comment: @jfriend00, to be loaded sometime in the future. I am newb to hacking. Playing around in rails. I am building a customization website. For example, customization of pizza. The user can select different variety of meat, cheese, and veggies. As they are being selected, the items are simultaneously being printed to a form. When the use clicks a submit button, the form is generated(?)... that way whoever is making the pizza can get a list of the items selected to actually make the pizza... sorry for any confusion this blurb may have caused.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a page that will be loaded sometime in the future.  That page doesn't exist yet.

All you can do is to set some state (in browser cookie, browser local storage or on the server) that the javascript code in that other page can examine and then modify that other page when it is loaded.